# Is possible to install angular cli not by cmd?

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

Is any other way to install angular cli than by commend in cmd?
When I run npm install -g @angular/cli I am getting problem with proxy settings (I am using vpn to work)

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to registry.npmjs failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
```

Can I add it by some .exe file or from .zip?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the zip file of your package you can install it with `npm` or `yarn`:

```
npm install ./package.zip
```

or

```
yarn add ./package.zip
```

PS: To pack your files (if you have the package) you can simply use `yarn pack .` inside the folder.